# Travelling to Mexico from the UK with a Polish passport

Tags: visas, paperwork, mexico, polish-citizens

My boyfriend and I have booked a holiday to Mexico. However, he has a Polish passport and I've been unable to find out if he'll need a visa or not. Any help on the matter will be greatly appreciated. I just want to make sure we are all prepared.

Comment: Does your boyfriend have a non-expired visa or permanent residence in the UK (or USA, Canada, Japan, Schengen)?

Comment: He has permanent residence in the UK

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan How is this relevant? No EU citizens require a visa.

Comment: @Coke Nobody with UK permanent residence needs a visa.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan A UK permanent residence permit, yes. EU citizens can't get one (unless you count the optional residency sticker issued for evidence purposes, which most people hardly bother to get), beacuse it's not applicable to them

Answer (score 14):

Here is the Mexican government's [list of countries that don't require a visa for Mexico](http://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-no-requieren-visa-para-mexico/), when entering as a tourist or other visitor without work permission.  It includes Poland ("Polonia").

Answer (score 9):

Per Timatic, the database used by airport check-in staff:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of Poland with a normal
>   passport for a maximum stay of 180 days

So no, he does **not** need a visa, and this is true for all EU/EFTA citizens

Answer (score 8):

He doesn't need a visa when travelling for up to 180 days.

From [Polish MFA travel guide](https://polakzagranica.msz.gov.pl/Meksykanskie,Stany,Zjednoczone,MEX.html) (in Polish):

> No visa is required for Polish citizens in the case of tourist, private or business stays not exceeding 180 days.